# shell script not breaking from the loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i am a neewbie to shell programming and tryin to implement some retry logic. for some reason my until loop is not exiting. its getting hanged there. any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
retry_cnt=0
until [ $retry_cnt -ge 3 ]; do
  echo "current retry count - " $retry_cnt
time my command here
daily_stat=$?
if [ $daily_stat -eq 0 ]; then 
break 
fi
retry_cnt=$[$retry_cnt+1]
sleep 5 
done
```

Comment: What is printed as `current retry count`?

Comment: it 0 only. once it enters the if condition for daily_stat, it got hang at break statement. any guess?

Comment: Are you sure it gets that far? It looks to me as though you are hanging on "my command". If you add ` -x` to the header line, you'll see every statement executed.

Comment: you are write.i found the issue, using -x debug mode. its something to do with my command. thanks for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was with undisclosed command.

Comment: @simee - I have summarised my comments as an answer, since the use of the `x` flag may be useful to others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions about your script:

- Use braces when calling variables, calling variables with `_` in its name and **without** braces can run into errors as bash can interpret the variable name as the 1st part, in this case: `$retry` (see [IFS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_07) on tldp)
- use [let for arithmetics](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html), it's really quick and easy to understand.
- Use [double brackets](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) (`[[`), is the evolution of single brackets (only if you use `bash` and not `sh`)

Try this version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
let retry_cnt=0
until [[ ${retry_cnt} -ge 3 ]] ; do
    echo "current retry count - ${retry_cnt}"
    time my command here
    daily_stat=$?
    if [[ ${daily_stat} -eq 0 ]] ; then 
        break
    fi
    let retry_cnt++
    sleep 5 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers to my comments, I guessed that it was your unnamed command that was hanging and not the script itself.

The way to verify this is to change the header line to:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

This causes every command executed to be displayed before execution, so you will see the command which causes the hang.

In a long script which may produce lots of irrelevant output you can leave the header line alone and instead trace a specific section of the script by adding these lines before and after:-

```
set -x
...
set +x
```